# PHP Imagick SVG to PNG not applying font

Tags: php, svg, fonts, png, imagick

I am trying to save an SVG file containing text with a non-system font as a PNG. I have converted the font as data64 as I read that should get around the web host needing to have the font installed. Although the SVG displays as normal in a web browser when I open the created png the text is displayed without the font applied. What am I doing wrong...

SVG data:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="3200" height="3200" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 3.2.0</desc>
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'ABeeZee';
            src: local('ABeeZee Regular'), local('ABeeZee-Regular'), url(data:font/woff;base64,[[Font Base64 placeholder due to character limit]]) format('woff');
        }
</style>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 200 23.5)" style="font-family:'ABeeZee' !important; ">
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="ABeeZee" font-size="32.410852713178286" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="font-family:'ABeeZee' !important; stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;"><tspan x="-102.09418605" y="10.18154527">Kent Patrick</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

PHP Code:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImageBlob( $svg );
$im->setImageFormat( "png24" );
$im->resizeImage( 1000, 1000, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1 );  /*Optional, if you need to resize*/

$im->writeImage( $save_file );

header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
echo $im;

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG is created with Fabric JS and I am assuming your Font is installed on the Canvas. You could convert the canvas to a PNG in Fabric JS. Try using multipier:2 this gives you a better image.

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', multiplier: 2});
```